# How to exit QGIS after running a python script?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I would like to run a python script via `qgis --code myscript.py` and then immediately exit.  I'm using `iface.actionExit().trigger()`, which kills QGIS when I run it from the python console, but not when put in the script that I pass to `--code`.

What's the right way to immediately exit?  I'm running QGIS 2.0.1

**Update**:  I've also tried `sys.exit()`.  QGIS catches it and pops up a window with the following:

```
An error occured during execution of following code:
  execfile('myscript.py')

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "myscript.py", line 14, in 
      sys.exit()
  SystemExit
```

**Update**: `os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)` works but it's a dirty hack and I'm looking for something better.

Comment: You can but why?

Comment: I'm automatically making a pdf with a print composer (the `--screenshot` flag just doesn't cut it).

Comment: Could you include your code into the question please as this could help potential answerers? I ask this as I also used `sys.exit()` in my scripts which have worked.

Comment: `echo "sys.exit()" > code.py; qgis --code code.py`
What version of QGIS were you running?  How were you invoking the scripts?

Answer (score 6):

Try in your script:

```
from qgis.utils import iface

#your code here

iface.actionExit().trigger()
```

It works for me.

**Editing Note:**

Based in Conley Owens'comment, I changed slightly my script to do "something useful" (where the line that import **iface** was commented).

```
#from qgis.utils import iface
import os

os.system('clear')
print "Hello"

iface.actionExit().trigger()
```

I ran **qgis --code myscript.py** at the bash console, inside the folder of the script, and immediately I got this error message:

[image]

and indicating that **from qgis.utils import iface** line is necessary.

When the first line is not commented the script execution had not errors:

[image]

but the control was not in the Python console; it is in the bash console (observe the "Hello" print there). For this reason your **os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)** command works because close the console and automatically close QGIS.

The solution to this issue, if I need the PyQGIS API outside QGIS, it was to include the PYTHONPATH to QGIS (**/usr/share/qgis/python**) in my **.bashrc** and to run the script in the bash console as **python myscript.py**. It works.

In Windows, you can get the PYTHONPATH in the Python Console of QGIS with:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

and use the Control Panel of Windows to change it.

Comment: I did try it (as noted in the original question).  It doesn't work.  Have you actually tried this from the `--code` option or only from the console?  What version of QGIS are you running?

Comment: Please, see my "Editing Note".

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not sure what you mean by running the script in the bash console as `python myscript.py`, are you suggesting I use the api outside of qgis where I would then have to handle all the overhead of running `QgsApplication.initQgis()` and loading the project myself?  If so, this is going an entirely different route.

Answer (score 2):

It works well for me to do this:

```
import os
os._exit(0)
```

It's also useful that you can set an exit code.